# JQuery extending a function is failing

Tags: jquery, function, extending

I am new to JQuery and am racking my brain trying to understand why this one code works, but mine does not.  Here is a snippet...

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    $('#mqTable tr.group1').css("background-color", "pink"); // This works
    $('#mqTable tr.group1').changeColor(); // Trying my own function fails


    // Prevent the warning message when leaving the page
    //        event.preventDefault();

    event.returnValue = "To be removed...";
  };

  jQuery.fn.extend({
    changeColor: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
      return $(this);
    }
  });
```

So, I am trying to create my own custom function, but I am doing something wrong.
Any ideas?

Comment: I want a function where I can set sessionStorage and this was just a test for me being able to call a function from a JQuery object.

Comment: Works fine here

Comment: Ha!  and Oh No!!  I am racking my brain trying to understand what could possibly be wrong.  I assume returning $(this) is necessary for chaining.  Or does it already do this "under the covers"?  I am REALLY pulling at straws!

Comment: Your code appears to work. If it doesn't for you, please make a [MCVE] illustrating the problem

Comment: I was able to find the error message by putting in a try/catch block

TypeError: $(...).changeColor is not a function

Still don't know why though!

Comment: I am making progress, but it is still failing....

I changed:     $( document ).ready(function() {

to:     $( document ).ready(function($) {

That helped!

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry, I don't know how to use Stack Overflow very well, so this is the only way I could find to format my code.

I can call the function from a button click and it understands it is an extended jQuery function.  But it fails when I try to call it from within an onbeforeunload function with the error: **TypeError: firstGroup1.children(...).changeColor is not a function**

[image]

The pictures shows I clicked on the Change Colors button and the group1 rows colors changed...so I know I have a valid custom jQuery function.   At the bottom is the error I get when I try to call the same function from onbeforeunload function.

The following is the relevant code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function($) {
    $('#changeColors').on('click',function(){
        try {
            var firstGroup1 = $('#mqTable tbody');
            firstGroup1.children("tr.group1").changeColor();
        }
        catch (err) {
            $('#errMsg').html(err);
        }
    });
});

window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    console.log("in onbeforeunload");
    var firstGroup1 = $('#mqTable tbody');
    try {
        firstGroup1.children("tr.group1, tr.group2").changeColor();
    } catch (err) {
        $('#errMsg').html(err);
    }

    // Prevent the warning message when leaving the page
    event.returnValue = "Oh boy";
};

jQuery.fn.extend({
    changeColor: function() {
        console.log("in changeColor");
        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
        return $(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok...I figured it out....

        window.onbeforeunload = function(event) { is now defined inside of document.ready and it seems to work fine.